# recursive function returns itself without being asked to

Tags: python, recursion

I have a prompt in terminal that is calling itself without being asked to. The behavior in question is if it is fed names like ['artist', 'art', 'dogs'], and the match matches 1 of them, when it reaches `elif len(matches) == 1:`, it will ask you to confirm "Is dogs OK?" twice. It always asks twice, then correctly returns 'dogs'

```
def hostfunc(names):

    def _prompt(answer=None):
        if answer == None:
            answer = gather("Pick from {names}...if you want more than 1, separate like \"name1, name2\"".format(names=names))
            _prompt(answer=answer)
        matches = check_for_answer_matches(names, answer)
        matches_string = process_matches(matches)
        if len(matches) == 0:
            answer = gather("That string didn't match any of {names}, please try again".format(names=names))
            _prompt(answer=answer)
        elif len(matches) == 1:
            answer = gather("Is {matches_string} OK? ('y' or 'n' to restart)".format(matches_string=matches_string))
            if answer == 'y':
                return matches
            elif answer == 'n':
                return _prompt()
            return matches
        elif len(matches) > 1:
            answer = gather("That string matched {matches_string}, is that OK? ('y' or 'n' to restart)".format(matches_string=matches_string))
            if answer == 'y':
                return matches
            elif answer == 'n':
                return _prompt()

    return _prompt()
```

I've been stuck on it all day because as I see it, the hostfunc tries to return prompt which sees it has no answer, and asks you to "Pick from...", which calls _prompt with the answer. _prompt sees it has an answer, gets the matches, and since `len(matches) == 1`, it should ask you if "Is dogs OK?" then immediately return `['dogs']` when you say 'y'.

I also tried doing `x = _prompt()` and then returning x instead. Why does this thing ask you to confirm twice? 
Thank you

Comment: can you provide your gather function so we can run it? EDIT: Have you tried placing a `return` after the `_prompt` call in if answer = None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `if answer == None` is not returning after calling `_prompt` again, so you'll iterate with the correct `answer` variable *twice*

so you'll call `_prompt()` with `answer=None`, which will prompt input and then call `_prompt(answer)`, which will find the correct matches. **but** once that `_prompt(answer)` call is finished, it will resume with the callee which now has answer set accordingly, making it technically run the final answer twice.

changing `_prompt(answer)` to `return _prompt(answer)` should fix this

Comment: ty, completely slipped my eyes